# How to play video file from asset library

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4, media-player, assetslibrary

How to play the video file from assets library? I have the URL of file like

```
"assets-library://asset/asset.MOV?id=1000000023&ext=MOV"
```

But I am unable to play this file in media player using the following code:

```
NSString *urlAddress = @"assets-library://asset/asset.mov?id=1000000023&ext=mov"; 
NSURL *theURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress]; 
MPMoviePlayerController *mp = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:theURL];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was also getting problem, and got the solution. I used the following code and it worked for me. The `urlAddress` is the url for the video by `ALAssetsLibrary`.

```
-(void)playVideo:(NSString *)urlAddress{

NSString *newUrl = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",urlAddress];

NSURL *theURL = [NSURL URLWithString:newUrl];

//player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];

[player setContentURL:theURL];
[player prepareToPlay];
[player play]; 

}
```

Comment: for those who can't get the video to play, call [player play]; after a short delay as object can take a while to prepare video

Comment: NSString *newUrl = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",urlAddress];
This does nothing. You create a string with the exact same string.

I still can't get anything to work in iOS 8 when I have a assets-library based URL for the media player.